# Eclipse + wxWidgets + Boost -- exceptions not being displayed

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, eclipse-cdt, boost-serialization

I've been coding a simple GUI address book program under Windows 7 x64, using wxWidgets2.8.12 and boost::serialization with mingw4.6 and Eclipse CDT Juno.

While coding functionality to serialize entries to/from a file using a boost::archive::text_iarchive and text_oarchive, I discovered the program would cease to work upon launch. It would simply start and then immediately terminate. g++ compiled it fine, and nothing was written to stdout or stderr. Upon using gdb to investigate the issue further I found out that there was indeed an exception being thrown by the boost library.

That, in itself, is not the issue. The issue is that this exception was never displayed in any of Eclipse's consoles, so I didn't even know it existed until stepping through the entire application. The exception itself is fairly simple to resolve, but has proven very problematic due to this lack of output. Nothing is displayed when building and running the application in both Debug and Release configurations.

My question, in essence, is this: Why are these library exceptions not being outputted, and what do I need to do to ensure their proper display? I haven't yet been able to find anything useful after searching a while, and any assistance would of course be appreciated. Thank you in advance to anyone who is able to help.

Comment: The first thing to do is open a mingw shell, find that compiled binary and try to run it from shell. Does it output the exception now? Then it could be an Eclipse issue, if you still don't see the exception output then Eclipse is not an issue and you can focus on wxWidgets and boost.

Comment: Just tried that. I get no output from the shell running the compiled executable from both Debug and Release directories, so that would seem to point something involving wxWidgets (or possibly boost, but the former seems more likely to me)

Answer (score 1):

Well one thing you could do, although it will require a catch block at the top level OR use of `set_unexpected()` is something like the following.

```
#include <boost/exception/diagnostic_information.hpp>

...

catch(...)
{
    std::cerr << "Unhandled exception!" << std::endl <<
    boost::current_exception_diagnostic_information();
    return 1; //or whatever...
}
```

You could filter out boost/std exceptions of course before the drastic `catch(...)` but you get the idea.

Edit:

The other reason you may not see an exception is if it is called (for some reason) during the stack unwinding - it would then call `terminate` and stop dead...

Comment: Not the cleanest thing in the world, but it seems to work, which is what's important. It does throw the exception with the proper info when placed around the exception-throwing code. The only thing is it doesn't really explain the problem, just overrides it. It would be useful to know the root cause for future code that may have similar problems. Overall though, it does seem to do what I need, at least for the time being.

Comment: Yeah I can understand your frustration with this kind of problem - I'm wracking my small store of brains to think why this might happen :) will update if I think of anything....

Comment: I'm guessing it's something to do with wxWidgets suppressing errors or some such. It doesn't seem to be coded with standards in mind, from what I've used of it. Had I the time, I'd probably switch to something like QT, but it's just a small app for a class (still learning), and even if I wanted to go to all that effort I wouldn't have the time to re-write everything.

Comment: wxWidgets definitely doesn't swallow any exceptions on its own. While it doesn't use any exceptions internally (not because it was coded without standards in mind but because it was started back when using C++ exceptions simply wasn't practical), it is exception safe in the sense that your event handlers can throw exceptions and you can catch them in `wxApp::OnExceptionInMainLoop()`. In my experience, blaming the tools you use is usually not the most productive way to approach the program resolution.

Comment: I'm not necessarily blaming it, I can't think of what would be causing an exception to not display at all. It may well be my code; I can hardly claim to be an experienced programmer, but it seems somewhat strange when I was not doing anything to manipulate exception throwing or handling in my source. Wouldn't exceptions generally have at least some output if not handled manually?

Comment: not necessarily no, it depends on the lib, it depends on the expectations of the lib on the user etc... In fact have you been used to Java type exceptions that are verbose and automatically output? Because C++ is not quite like that - I kind of assumed that you'd had a catch but either the type wasn't handled or something odd happened to stop it working